# is there any way to install cupy without Cuda

Tags: python-3.x, linux, pip, cupy

`pip install cupy` won't install cupy without cuda.

Linux: lubuntu v21.10
pip v3.10
conda v22.11.1

I have linux installed on an older laptop and it doesn't have any dedicated GPU.
I have a [python framework](https://github.com/phuselab/pyVHR) I'm trying to test out and it requires cupy to run. I tried `pip install cupy` but it wouldn't run without any cuda installation.

I tried `conda install cupy` but the framework won't run when conda install cuda

Answer (score 2):

https://pypi.org/project/cupy/ is "NumPy & SciPy **for GPU**" (emphasize mine — *phd*). You cannot install it without CUDA.

If you want to use pyVHR without GPU you need to switch to the branch [pyVHR_CPU](https://github.com/phuselab/pyVHR/tree/pyVHR_CPU). There is `pyVHR_CPU_env.yml` to create CPU-ony `conda` environment. See the [installation instructions](https://github.com/phuselab/pyVHR/tree/pyVHR_CPU#getting-started).

Another approach would be to install an emulator (`qemu`, VirtualBox, etc.) and configure it to emulate a GPU. Not sure if it worth the trouble in terms of speed.